# Parse json into a clickable listview

Tags: android, json, android-layout

Hi I'm parsing JSON some thing like this.

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    for (Shop shop : this.response.shops) {

        builder.append(String.format("<br>ID: <b>%s</b><br>Shop: <b>%s</b><br>Description: <b>%s</b><br><br>", shop.getId(), shop.getName(), shop.getDescription()));

    }

    capitalTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(builder.toString()));
    progressDialog.cancel();
}
```

Now I want to parse this into a list. But I couldn't implement it. Any help? may be sample code please?

Comment: A list as in a regular string list?

Comment: yap. but with images and clickable

Comment: So you're trying to make a `ListView`?

Comment: yes but I want to fetch the json data into the list (eg: shop.getName() and shop.getImg())

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is create a `ListView` backed by an `Adapter` that you can use to display this content. There are a lot of tutorials on how to do this - [here's one](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

I would suggest you create a `Class` to represent what you're displaying in the list. From what I can see above it looks like its a shop. Then you would set the values of that object to be whatever you are getting from the `JSON` and add that object - one for each shop - to the `Adapter`. This will allow you to then display the contents in a `ListView` that you can layout anyway you want.

Answer (score 0):

There's a [really cool library](https://github.com/koush/ion) that does exactly what you are looking for, and simplifies implementation in the process. It will do the network request for you, so you don't have to worry about AsyncTask or anything, it uses GSON to incorporate your own models (classes) into the process.

For instace, say your class is:

```
public class Shop {

@Expose
@SerializedName("shop_name")
private String shopName = null;
public void setShopName(String shopName) {
    this.shopName = shopName;
}
public String getShopName() {
    return shopName;
}

@Expose
@SerializedName("shop_image")
private String shopImage = null;
public void setShopImage(String shopImage) {
    this.shopImage = shopImage;
}
public String getShopImage() {
    return shopName;
}
}
```

Then you can make a simple request and turn into a ListView like this:

```
public void getShopDetails(final Context context) throws Exception {
    Ion.with(context, "http://example.com/api/shopitems")
            .as(new TypeToken<List<Shop>>(){});
    .setCallback(new FutureCallback<List<Shop>>() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(Exception e, List<Shop> shopitems) {
            //Set your custom adapter
        }
    });
}
```

Your custom adapter can be something really simple, and you don't have to handle the JSON at all, just use your custom class getter and setters. I hope that helps!